# Cheap ASP.NET Hosting - Mutiple Domains

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Can anybody recommend some quality ASP.NET hosting providers that allow you to multiple domains without making you use a "reseller" account or purchase multiple accounts. I really only need email accounts for one of the domains.

I'm looking for something about $20 to $45 USD.

Answer (score 3):

I use [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com) and the second tier hosting allows you to host multiple domains.

Comment: what do you mean by second tier? It looks like they only allow you 200MB MSSQL Database size... is that right?

Comment: Godaddy has the 200mb database size yes.  But the second tier web hosting plan allows for an unlimited amount of domain hosting.  as well as unlimited sub domains.( I imagine its not really unlimited, but that is what the advertise)

Answer (score 0):

Mosso acquired by [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/) has a basic plan that you you can create unlimited ASP, ASP.NET, PHP, Perl, and RoR sites on their cloud.

Answer (score 0):

[GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com) offers affordable hosting and is considered one of the cheapest hosting service around. I haven't faced any issues after hosting my site there. I have hosted 2 domains there.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Windows VPS with [VPS Land](http://vpsland.com/) and they are pretty cheap. Simply pay for the HDD/RAM/CPU and your able to host as many sites as you want, increase the spec when you hit a performance plateau. It's not running Plesk or whatever so you need to be a little familiar with IIS and Server 2003.